# Decompose lines of standard powerpoint shape

Tags: powerpoint, shapes

I would like to split a standard PowerPoint shape into separate lines so that I can have full control over how and when they appear when using animations. Thus, I would like to see that the shape on top (a standard PowerPoint shape) is decomposed in the one below (without the space betwen the lines.

[image]

I hope somebody has some creative ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This may help get started.  Look up the docs on the various properties/methods for more information.

```
Sub thing()

    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    Dim pointsArray()

    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    With oSh
        Debug.Print .Nodes.Count

        With .Nodes
            For x = 1 To .Count

                Debug.Print "X = " & .Item(x).Points(1, 1)
                Debug.Print "Y = " & .Item(x).Points(1, 2)

            Next
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```